# Raspberry PI Tomcat7 and Serial Port Communication using ISO8859-7

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to relay a message from a Servlet to COM in raspberry pi on Tomcat 7.

I am using null cable between raspberry and my PCs to test.

I am using jssc API (Java Simple Serial Connector) for serial communication.

Raspberry pi is using JDK 1.8.0_65.

I am getting the message in UTF8 and I should output it in ISO8859-7.

Since UTF8 is a superset of ISO8859-7, the app that calls the servlet ensures all characters sent are legitimate for ISO8859-7.

My code:

```
package com.test.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import jssc.*;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(value = "/Relay", name = "Relay")
public class Relay extends HttpServlet {

    static Logger app = null;
    static {
        app = Logger.getLogger("com.test.app");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

        try {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-7");;
            response.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-7");
            //request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            //response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            String message = request.getParameter("message");



            app.logp(Level.INFO, this.getClass().getCanonicalName(),"APP", message);
            String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();

            app.logp(Level.INFO, this.getClass().getCanonicalName(),"APP", portNames.length+"");

            for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){

                applogp(Level.INFO, this.getClass().getCanonicalName(),"APP", portNames[i]);

                byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
                msg = message.getBytes("ISO-8859-7");

                Charset utf8charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
                Charset iso88597charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-7");
                ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes());
                CharBuffer data = utf8charset.decode(inputBuffer);
                ByteBuffer outputBuffer = iso88597charset.encode(data);
                byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();


                byte[] b1 = message.getBytes();
                byte[] b2 = message.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-7"));
                byte[] b3 = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);


                SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort((portNames[i]));
                try {
                    serialPort.openPort();
                    serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                    serialPort.writeBytes(msg);
                    serialPort.writeBytes(message.getBytes());
                    serialPort.writeBytes(outputData);
                    serialPort.writeBytes(b1);
                    serialPort.writeBytes(b2);
                    serialPort.writeBytes(b3);
                    serialPort.closePort();


                } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    app.logp(Level.INFO, this.getClass().getCanonicalName(),"APP", ex.getMessage());
                    out.write("NOK");
                    out.close();
                }
            }
            out.write("OK");
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            app.logp(Level.INFO, this.getClass().getCanonicalName(),"APP", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

The problem is that when I am testing I do not get valid output in putty.
[putty output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap7me.png)

I have configured putty to display ISO8859-7 characters.

Any for changes ? 
What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to divide the problem by producing the following code:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class SerialTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "message μήνυμα";
        if ( sendTextOnCom(message) ) {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS MESSAGE SENT");
        }
        else{ 
            System.out.println("FAIL MESSAGE NOT SENT");
        }

    }
    private static boolean sendTextOnCom(String message) {
        boolean isOverlaid = false; 
        SerialPort com = null;
        try {
            String comNo = "COM1"; // String comNo="/dev/ttyUSB0"; //when used in Raspberry 
            com = new SerialPort(comNo);
            com.openPort(); 
            com.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);           
            com.writeString(message);
            com.writeBytes(message.getBytes("ISO-8859-7"));
            com.closePort();
            isOverlaid = true;
        }
        catch (SerialPortException  ex) {
            System.out.println("[ERROR] COM ERROR SENDING MESSAGE");
            isOverlaid = false;
            try {
                com.closePort();
            } catch (SerialPortException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return isOverlaid;
    }
}
```

The code is working normally in Windows 7 64bit and it is producing output in putty with the right characters.

When I compile and run the same code in raspberry PI the output in putty is not showing the valid characters.

I tend to think that it's a raspberry PI configuration issue.